# How to list properties of a PowerShell object excluding those starting with '_'?

Tags: powershell, properties, filter, wmi

I want to select only the properties which names do not start with '__'.
For example:

```
$cpu = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor
$cpu | Get-Member -MemberType Property
```

Returns:

```
__CLASS
__DERIVATION
__DYNASTY
__GENUS
__NAMESPACE
__PATH
__PROPERTY_COUNT
__RELPATH
__SERVER
__SUPERCLASS
```

The only way I've found to filter those out is:

```
$cpu | Select-Object ($cpu | Get-Member -MemberType Property | Select-Object Name | Where-Object {$_.Name -NotMatch '^_.*$'} | ForEach-Object {$_.name})
```

It looks very inefficient. Is there a faster way?

Answer (score 0):

Try looking at the CIM cmdlets instead. They expose the same information but are basically better in most respects. Here is a [basic intro](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2012/08/24/introduction-to-cim-cmdlets.aspx) to the CIM cmdlets to get you started. If you only want the names of the properties, you could rewrite the above as:

```
Get-CimInstance CIM_Processor | get-member -membertype Property
```

If you are stuck on WMI you can just use:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | get-member -membertype Property `
| Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch '__'}
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the CIM cmdlets. I'll read more about them.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

$cpu = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select [a-z]*

Comment: How  does the select parse that? As a simple match only? It looks more like a regex which I though select didn't do. Handy but I've never seen the syntax.

Comment: It's a wildcard match.  I believe the [a-z] range matching was added in V3.

Answer (score 0):

I created this little command that works with WMI and CIM objects

https://gist.github.com/brendanmeyer/59a4c45736aa9f52f8aa88c49820e7f9

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor | Select-WMICIMProperties
Get-CimInstance Win32_Processor | Select-WMICIMProperties
```